# Am I going to be able to move my character from Closed Beta to final product?

Tags: vindictus

I am participating in the closed beta of Vindictus Europe and have been enjoying the game so far.

I invested a lot of time into the design and development of my character, and, I'd like to spend a long time with it.

Does anyone have any idea, whether it will be possible to go on seamlessly with it in the final product?

Comment: While in most cases I'd recommend Gaming.SE as the place to go to get knowledgeable answers to questions about games, this question seems like it should be asked of the game's developers. I'd think they would have a forum or ten set up for bug reports and questions from people in the beta where you could get the answer to your question directly from the people who decide what that answer will be.

Comment: Since there is no official announcement and all the answers are based on speculation, I'm suggesting we close this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://news.mmosite.com/content/2011-09-27/vindictus_european_open_beta_kicks_off_immediately.shtml) source, you will not.  Its weird because between the [original](http://ve3d.ign.com/articles/news/57170/Vindictus-Open-Beta-Starts) game, you could.

Answer (score 3):

You should not expect so. It is very rare that stuff from closed or open betas gets moved into the final product.

Comment: Which would also be my obvious answer, given no further clue. But, you know, I'm looking in the sky for a flicker of hope :)